# Remove Subdocument items with $pull

Tags: express, mongoose, pull

I'm trying to remove items from subdocuments using ExpressJS and Mongoose but it is only removing the first items, not the sub items.

So I want to remove "subitem 2" in the messages Array
This is the structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c4ee94b30ebd71cbed89a35"),
    "title" : "Test",
    "subitem" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5c4ee95630ebd71cbed89a36"),
            "title" : "Item 1",
            "messages" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5c4ee95f30ebd71cbed89a37"),
                    "type" : "single_article",
                    "date" : "Jan 28, 2019",
                    "title" : "subitem 1",
                    "text" : ""
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5c4ee96830ebd71cbed89a38"),
            "title" : "item 2",
            "messages" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5c4ee96e30ebd71cbed89a39"),
                    "type" : "single_article",
                    "date" : "Jan 28, 2019",
                    "title" : "subitem 2",
                    "text" : ""
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

And this is the $pull method:

```
getController.deleteRec = function(req,res,collection){
  var id = req.params.id;
  console.log(id);
  collection.updateOne({'subitem.messages._id': id}, {$pull: {'subitem.0.messages': {"_id": id}}}).
    then(function(result){
      console.log(result);
    });
};
```

Now I know why it is only deleting the first item because I have "subitem.0.messages". How can I loop over this, so it can delete all items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$` as a wildcard index, removing all elements in the array matching your query like this:

```
{$pull: {'subitem.$.messages': {"_id": id}}}
```

if you want to remove multiple documents:

```
{$pull: {'subitem.$.messages': {"_id": {$in : [id, id2, id3...]}}}}
```